# Remove Hashbang from url using redux-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

Hashbang(#!) is getting appended to the url when using react-router.

Ex: http://localhost:3000/#!/?

Sample code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import { reduxReactRouter, routerStateReducer, ReduxRouter } from 'redux-router';
import { createHistory } from 'history';
import { Route } from 'react-router';

const routes = (
   <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="parent" component={Parent}>
    <Route path="child" component={Child} />
    <Route path="child/:id" component={Child} />
   </Route> );

   const reducer = combineReducers({
    router: routerStateReducer,
   });

   const store = compose(
    applyMiddleware(m1, m2, m3),
    reduxReactRouter({
    routes,
    createHistory
   }),
   devTools()
   )(createStore)(reducer);
```

How to remove Hashbang from the URL?

Comment: I think you mean react-router, as redux-router is just a layer on that. And also please specify the version.

Comment: You will not be able to change this behaviour since this is how the react router works. It is listening on the HashChange event to identify changes in your URL.

Comment: react-router: 1.0.0-rc3, redux-router: 1.0.0-beta5

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to get rid of hash urls all together (hashbang is when it has a `!` too).

Follow the instructions here:

https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#browserhistory

They show you an example using Express (though it's possible with pretty much any server):

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
const app = express()

// serve static assets normally
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

// handle every other route with index.html, which will contain
// a script tag to your application's JavaScript file(s).
app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(port)
console.log("server started on port " + port)
```

I recommend to ensure the instructions are correct, update react-router to `2.0.0-rc4`, though at a glance it looks like this part of the guide still applies without changes.

The essence is that your server catches requests to real physical files first, then any remaining GET requests get sent to `index.html`.

There's a more advanced approach to this for [server-side rendering](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/advanced/ServerRendering.md) where the requests are passed through a router but I'll ignore that for now.

Then on the client you should use `browserHistory`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { browserHistory, Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'

import App from '../components/App'
import Home from '../components/Home'
import About from '../components/About'
import Features from '../components/Features'

render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path='about' component={About} />
      <Route path='features' component={Features} />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Comment: Dominic thanks for the info. Actually it was my mistake, i was using "qs" package for appending some stuffs to the url. It was creating the issue.